# What is really happening in this bash code that creates a shell with netcat and pipes?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, sh, netcat

```
mkfifo /tmp/f ; cat /tmp/f | /bin/bash -i 2>&1 | nc -l -p 1234 > /tmp/f
```

I am new to bash, I am trying to understand this piece of "code".

1. Why a while loop is not needed? How can this work? Is it itself a loop? Why? How?
   Also, `cat filePipe` by itself ONLY PRINTS ONE LINE, and then exits (I just tested it), and to make cat not to exit I do: `while cat pipeFile ; do : ; done`. So how does that above work?
2. I don't get the order of execution... at the beginning /tmp/f is empty, so cat /tmp/f should "send" an empty stream to /bin/bash which just send it to nc which opens a connection and "sends" the interactive bash to whoever connects... and the response of the client is sent to /tmp/f ... and then? What? How can it can go back and do the same things again?

Comment: `cat filePipe` does not print only one line.  It reads the fifo until whatever is writing to the other end of the fifo exits.  If your test case prints only one line, it is because the producer only wrote one line.  But in your example, `nc` is writing more than one line.  (And not exiting)

Comment: You must have some inkling what it does if you are surprised by the lack of a loop. Do you know what a fifo is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `bash` parses the line `mkfifo /tmp/f ; cat /tmp/f | /bin/bash -i 2>&1 | nc -l -p 1234 > /tmp/f`, several things happen.  First, the fifo is created.  Then, in no particular order, 3 things happen: `cat` is started, `bash` is started and `nc` is started with its output stream connected to `/tmp/f`.  `cat` is now going to block until some other process opens `/tmp/f` for writing; the `nc` is about to do that (or already did it, but we don't know if `cat` will start before `nc` or if `nc` starts before `cat`, nor do we know in which order they will open the fifo, but whoever does it first will block until the other completes the operation).  Once all 3 processes start, they will just sit there waiting for some data.  Eventually, some external process connects to port 1234 and sends some data into `nc`, which writes into `/tmp/f`.  `cat` (eventually) reads that data and sends it downstream to `bash`, which processes the input and (probably) writes some data into `nc`, which sends it back across the socket connection.

If you have a test case in which `cat /tmp/f` only writes one line of data, that is simply because whatever process you used to write into `/tmp/f` only wrote a single line.  Try: `printf 'foo\nbar\nbaz\n' > /tmp/f & cat /tmp/f` or `while sleep 1; do date; done > /tmp/f & cat /tmp/f`

Answer (score 1):

/tmp/f is NOT empty, but a fifo, a bi-directional link.

[image]

Someone connects to port 1234, type something, which `nc` will forward to `fifo` which then feeds into `bash`.

`bash` runs the command and sends results back to `nc`.

Answer (score 1):

#### .1 You misunderstand what happen when you `echo "string" >/path/fifo`

.a) When you just `echo something >/path/to/somewhere`, you

- (test accessibility, then) **open** target *somewhere* for writting
- **write** *someting* in openned *file descriptor* (*`fd`*)
- **close** (relax) accessed file.

.b) A *[fifo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))* (*The **F**irst **I**n is the **F**irst **O**ut.*) is not a file.

Try this:

> # Window 1:
>
> ```
> mkfifo /tmp/fifotest
> cat /tmp/fifotest
> ```

> # Window 2:
>
> ```
> exec {fd2fifo}>/tmp/fifotest
> echo >&$fd2fifo Foo bar
> ```

You will see `cat` **not terminating**.

> ```
> echo >&$fd2fifo Baz
> exec {fd2fifo}>&-
> ```

Now, cat will close

So there is no need of any loop!

#### .2 command `cat /tmp/f | /bin/bash -i 2>&1 | nc -l -p 1234 > /tmp/f`

could be written (***avoid useless use of `cat`***):

```
bash -i 2>&1 </tmp/f | nc -l -p 1234 > /tmp/f
```

but you could do **same** operation but from different *point of vue*:

```
nc -l -p 1234 </tmp/f | bash -i >/tmp/f 2>&1
```

The goal is

- to *drive* bash's *STDIN* from `nc`'s *STDOUT* and
- *connect back* bash's *STDOUT* and *STDERR* to `nc`'s *STDIN*.

### .3 The more: *bashism*

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could avoid creating *fifo* by using *unnamed fifo*:

```
coproc nc -l -p 1234; bash -i >&${COPROC[1]} 2>&1 <&${COPROC[0]}
```

or

```
exec {ncin}<> <(:); nc -l -p 1234 <&$ncin | bash -i >&$ncin 2>&1
```